# cordova build target name

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build a android app using cordova framework
The problem is when i try to build the app using `cordova build` the project name becomes MainActivity and so my apk name as well

[image]

I don't understand why because when i created the project , i didn't specify MainActivity as project name : `cordova create cordova_test com.dev.test myFirstCordovaApp`

Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't happen with Build Tools 21.1.2, with a project target of Android 4.4.2.   I will need to upgrade, I suppose to see. But when I use these commands to create my project, and then build, I don't get that.

cordova create cordova_test com.dev.test myFirstCordovaApp

cordova platform add android

cordova build

Comment: @Steve Kennedy. Thank you very much . The problem was about the recent cordova versions . I posted the answer and the article related.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem occurs with the latest versions of cordova
I manage to resolve the problem by following this article : http://www.cordovacircus.com/articles/cordova-android-name